# Obtain compiler flags in skylark

Tags: bazel

I'd like to convert a CMake-based C++ library to bazel.

As part of the current CMake project, I'm using a libclang-based code generator that parses C++ headers and generates C++ code from the parsed AST. In order to do that, I need the actual compiler flags used to build the `cc_library` the header is part of. The flags are passed to the code generation tool so it can use clang's preprocessor.

Is there any way I could access the compiler flags used to build a dependency from a skylark- or gen_rule rule? I'm particularly interested in the include paths and defines.

Comment: What builds the header, is there a genrule or some other rule to do so?

Comment: It is part of a cc_library rule.

Comment: Sorry, still confused. "In order to do that, I need the actual compiler flags used to build the header." -- this sounds like the header file is an output of the compiler. Is that somehow the case? Could you maybe give a simple example of the pipeline here?

Comment: Sorry, I was being imprecise. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on it. Well, not right now, but will soon. You might want to subscribe to [the corresponding issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2163), and maybe describe your requirements there so we take them into account when designing the API.